# Enviar un formulario cuando se marca checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Estoy enviando datos de mi formulario mediante ajax y la estructura de mi codigo es esta, y tengo un checkbox que tiene que estar seleccionado para enviar mis datos, pero aun no logro hacer que me aparezca el alert en mi funcion cuando el checkbox no esta seleccionado.

```
$(function(){      
  $('#userForm').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();        
    let first_name = $('#first_name');
    let last_name = $('#last_name');

    $.ajax({
      url: '/user/signup',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        first_name: first_name.val(),
        last_name: last_name.val(),
      },
      success: function (res){
        console.log(res);
      }
    })

  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ponle un `required` al *checkbox* dentro del *HTML* o comprueba si está seleccionado con

```
if( $('#checkbox').prop('checked') ) {
    alert('Seleccionado');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saber si un checkbox esta seleccionando puedes usar:

```
$('#myCheck').prop('checked')
```

Ya que en el caso the checkboxes no es valid usar val();

Para detener la ejecucion de codigo puedes tirar un error antes del alert:

```
throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!");
```